# Jquery tools overlay: Need to have rel="nofollow" when opening external page in overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

We have a page where different links can open different external pages in an jquery tools overlay, like it is explained on this page: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html.

Now our problem is that we also need to add NOFOLLOW to our rel-attribute since we don't want Google to index the content of the external page but this will break the overlay-functionality since the id of the overlay does not contain the word NOFOLLOW.

I had an idea of adding NOFOLLOW also to the id of the overlay but that will not work unfortunately, any ideas about how this is possible to solve?

Best regards
Martin

Comment: You will need to add the attribute on server side - a jQuery-generated `nofollow` won't be picked up by the search engine robot.

Comment: Pekka, adding the attribute NOFOLLOW server side or adding it straight in my HTML will still break the Jquery Tools Overlay plugin. Without NOFOLLOW my rel-tag looks something like this rel="#overlay" but I need it to be something like rel="#overlay NOFOLLOW" but this will cause the overlay plugin to not find which overlay to open up.

Comment: The examples in the overlay docs use `img` elements, though? Are you applying the attribute to `a` elements? (Because `nofollow` on an image doesn't make sense AFAIK)

Comment: Can't see that img elements are being used here, http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html, but a-elements with rel="#overlay"? So using the example on this page I'd like to tell Google to not index "external-content.htm" by using a NOFOLLOW in rel.

Comment: Ah, true. I was in the wrong section

Answer (score 0):

As said, you will need to serve the `nofollow` from server side, otherwise Google won't pick it up. The only idea that comes to mind to do that is

- serve `<a rel="nofollow" data-overlay="yes" ...>` from server side. The `data-` is for the next step which we do in jQuery
- before initializing the overlay, in jQuery, walk through every element and change the `rel` attribute from `nofollow` to `overlay`:

  ```
  $('[data-overlay="yes"]').attr("rel", "overlay");  // not tested 
                                                     // but should work
  ```
- initialize the overlay
- job done. Get some ice cream!